# Disable visual studio 2013 old project converter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Recently, I installed VS 2013 for my own computer. However, I still have some project that created by VS 2010. The uncomfortable thing is, my VS 2013 automatically convert my old project to VS 2013.

Is there anyway to disable the automation conversion of VS 2013?

EDIT: Instead of opening the project by VS2013, it should work well with Visual Studio Versions Selector. However, the issue can appear again on project that was used to be developed on VS2003, VS2005 and VS2008

Comment: The conversion is required for you to open the project in VS 2013. Why is the conversion an uncomfortable thing?

Comment: @LukkhaCoder I set the default is VS2013. However, these projects should be edit in VS2010 to maintain between different computers (other computer will not have VS2013)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266706.aspx

Comment: @Quannt I'm trying to find a way to stop the automation converter of VS2013 (could be manual like VS2010). I don't prefer to run my old project on VS2013

Comment: What happens when to set the default program for the solution file to "Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector"?

Comment: Recently, i also found out that "MVS Version Selector" would work well between VS2010 and VS2013, thanks. However, there was some project that the Selector can't decide between VS2008, V2005 and VS2003